# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, исключения, компиляция, locale

При запуске программы, реализующей анализ даты и времени, с использованием класса `LocaleDateTime`:

```
// Parse a date and time. 
import java.time.*; 
import java.time.format.*; 

class DateTimeDemo4 { 
  public static void main(String args[]) { 

    // Obtain a LocalDateTime object by parsing a date and time string. 
    LocalDateTime curDateTime = 
         LocalDateTime.parse("June 21, 2014 12:01 AM", 
                  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d',' yyyy hh':'mm a")); 

     // Now, display the parsed date and time. 
    System.out.println(curDateTime.format( 
               DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d',' yyyy h':'mm a"))); 
  } 
}
```

Постоянно выводится исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'June 21, 2014 12:01 AM' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at DateTimeDemo4.DateTimeDemo4.main(DateTimeDemo4.java:12)
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, исключение выводится из-за того, что Ваш компьютер соответствует [неверной языковой локации](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18727913/8370915) (в данном случае используется *английская*). Следовательно, её нужно явно указать.

### Решение

---

Указываем `Locale.US` в данном примере:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.Locale;

class DateTimeDemo4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Obtain a LocalDateTime object by parsing a date and time string.
        LocalDateTime curDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("June 21, 2014 12:01 AM",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d',' yyyy hh':'mm a", Locale.US));

        // Now, display the parsed date and time.
        System.out.println(curDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d',' yyyy hh':'mm a", Locale.US)));
    }
}
```

Получаем ожидаемый результат:

```
June 21, 2014 12:01 AM
```