# Метод не может распарсить дату

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Вот собственно код  дата прилетает формата 05 ноя 18, 20:51
В среде всё работает, но когда я компилирую файл и запускаю его через командную строку, то сыпятся ошибки:

```
private LocalDateTime refactorDate(String date) {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = null;

            dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date.replace("й", "я"), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MM yy, HH:mm"));
        }
        return dateTime;
    }
```

> ```
> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05 ноя 18, 20:51' could not be parsed at index 3
>    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
>    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
>    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
>    at ru.job4j.Parser.refactorDate(Parser.java:192)
> ```

будто ему слово **ноя** не нравится, но в среде IDEA всё работает как сделать, чтобы и в консоли работало? Что ему не нравится?

Comment: Попробуйте изменить [языковую локацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864546/260756), указав её явно.

Answer (score 1):

LocalDateTime.parse принимает только английские месяцы MMM и числа MM до 12

```
private static LocalDateTime refactorDate(String date) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime;

    dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(
            date.replace("ноя", "Nov"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yy, HH:mm"));
    return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: Но в среде же всё работает..

Comment: возможно ваша проблема в другом, например если у вас несколько функций main в разных классах то при нажатии ctrl+f5 IDEA запускает  функцию main из другого класса и вы думаете что всё работает, еще возможно вы указали другой входной класс при компиляции файла.                                                                                                                      А также, я хотел спросить:   в предложенном вами вверху коде, в 5 строчке скобка  }  не является лишней?

Comment: Нет это вырезка из кода,  я кое что удалил но суть дела не меняет. При компиляци. И при тестах один и тот же майн использую...

Comment: А что выводит в консоль в случае студии?

Comment: System.out.println(refactorDate(date));

Comment: судя по ошибке вы передаёте именно "05 ноя 18, 20:51"                                                                      java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '05 ноя 18, 20:51' could not be parsed at index 3

Comment: на винде 7 всё работает, на десятки вот таких гусей гонит

Comment: так что будет если в вашей студии вывести время? System.out.println(refactorDate( "05 ноя 18, 20:51"));

Comment: 06 ноя 18, 20:31
06 ноя 18, 16:56
06 ноя 18, 16:54
06 ноя 18, 16:19
06 ноя 18, 16:11
06 ноя 18, 14:54
06 ноя 18, 14:34
06 ноя 18, 14:32
06 ноя 18, 10:39
06 ноя 18, 10:06
05 ноя 18, 20:51
05 ноя 18, 15:34

Comment: да выводом в консоль я занимался всё чётко выводит

Comment: System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now()); выводит: 2018-11-08T06:04:22.088

Comment: System.out.println( "05 ноя 18, 20:51"); выводит: 05 ноя 18, 20:51

Comment: System.out.println(refactorDate("05 ноя 18, 20:51")); должно выводить: 2018-11-05T20:51

Comment: если у вас на выводе 06 ноя 18, 20:31 вместо  2018-11-05T20:51 то ваша программа просто выводит String date, а не LocalDateTime, это означает что код функции refactorDate в среде просто не используется, Почему?, а вот при компиляции в файл, этот код используется и выдаётся ошибка

Comment: DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yy, HH:mm")  работает! дело не в коде, а в ОС если запускать на семёрке то всё пашет прекрасно, если на десятке то ничего не работает, однако если запускать из среды то опять же всё работает без разницы семёрка это или десятка но если запускать собранный jar файл то на десятке не хочет работать!!! я слышал что есть ключи можно указать ключ запуска с параметрами локальной даты как это сделать?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args){}

Comment: String[] args это параметры передаваемые программе из cmd, если вы об этом

Comment: java -jar program.jar "05 ноя 18, 20:51"

Comment: ключ не нужен, всё что после program.jar (с пробелом) считается за параметры(аргументы),параметры отделяются пробелами и превращаются в массив строк `String[] args`, кавычки "" объединяют несколько аргументов в один, потом можно вытащить в программе `String date = args[0];`